# Unit testing of Jenkins Shared Library

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, shared-libraries

Can anyone suggest me the best way to create unit test cases for Jenkins pipeline Shared library?

Comment: At least for me it's unclear in what way the test should be "the best".

Answer (score 2):

I had used this framework https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit which did all work for jenkins pipeline as well as for shared libraries

Answer (score 1):

There is also the **Jenkins Spock** project: https://github.com/homeaway/jenkins-spock